# actualizar valor de array php

Tags: php

Necesito agregar información a un array que ya tengo definido, lo que sucede es que al recorrerlo me gustaría adicionar una descripción a cada valor, entiendo que debería generar un nuevo array asociativo en este caso y agregarle como clave el valor y como valor la descripción. Es correcto? o hay alguna manera de hacerlo sin generar otro array?

```
   $array = [0,0,1,1];
```

donde 0 significa "vacío" y 1 significa "ocupado". La idea es que me muestre:

```
   0 -> vacio
   0 -> vacio
   1 -> ocupado
   1 -> ocupado
```

Gracias!

Comment: Usas los 0 y 1 como valor ? o como claves ??

Comment: son valores, es un array básico de ceros y unos

Comment: Tendrías que crear un array asociativo con índices únicos lo cual aumentaría innecesariamente la complejidad. Y de todas formas si 0 es vacio y 1 ocupado ya no es necesario agregarle descripción porque sería redundante. Simplemente si necesitas mostrar la descripción, convertir el valor a cadena dentro de la programación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo no trataría de modificar los datos para el caso que expones, simplemente crearía un nuevo array para los estatus y buscaría en ese array el estatus que deberá mostrarse (vacío u ocupado).

Por ejemplo:

```
$mStatus=array('Vacío','Ocupado');
$array = array(0,0,1,1);

foreach ($array as $v){
    echo $mStatus[$v].PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Vacío
Vacío
Ocupado
Ocupado
```

Una de las grandes ventajas de esto es que no tienes un montón de **datos redundantes** en el array final diciendo: vacío, ocupado, ocupado, vacío .... hasta `N`  veces, donde `N` sería el total de elementos en `$array`

Otra ventaja es la **portabilidad**. Supongamos que debe agregarse otro estatus bajo un índice `2`, pues lo agregas directamente en `$mStatus`, sin tener que modificar nada más en el `foreach`.

Veamos:

```
$mStatus=array('Vacío','Ocupado','Reservado');
$array = array(0,0,1,1,2,1,0,2,1);

foreach ($array as $v){
    echo $mStatus[$v].PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Vacío
Vacío
Ocupado
Ocupado
Reservado
Ocupado
Vacío
Reservado
Ocupado
```

Por último, cabde decir que los valores de `$mStatus` tienen cada uno su índice, aunque sea de forma implícita, por eso cada valor es encontrado al hacer: `$mStatus[$v]` .

Podemos inspeccionar el elemento:

```
var_dump($mStatus);
```

**Salida:**

Se aprecian los índices: `0`, `1` y `2`.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Vacío"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Ocupado"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "Reservado"
}
```

Y ya, esta vez sí, por último, la parte del `foreach` debería ser perfeccionada, verificando que la clave a buscar existe en el array y quizá estableciendo un valor por defecto para los casos en que no exista.

Comment: Excelente como siempre, muy agradecido por tu aporte.